# Is $i\notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ for all odd primes $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

My main question is the title: for an odd prime $p$, denote a primitive $p^{\text{th}}$ root of unity by $\zeta_p$.  Is it true that $i$ is not contained in the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$? If this is true, is the following proof correct, and if it is not true, where does the following proof break down:

Recall that the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm p})$ where there is a $"+"$ is $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$ and a $"-"$ if $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ (Source: exercise 11 of section 14.7 of Dummit and Foote). Assume to the contrary that $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 2 contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.  But this yields an immediate contradiction since of course $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm p}) \neq \mathbb{Q}(i)$. So $i\notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: I think your proof looks fine..

Comment: If $i \in \Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$, then $2$ would be ramified in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ (since it is ramified in $\Bbb Q(i)$), which is not possible as only $p$ ramifies in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ (and $p$ is odd).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another proof: if $i\in{\mathbb Q}(\zeta_p)$ then ${\mathbb Q}(i\zeta_p) \subseteq {\mathbb Q}(\zeta_p)$. But $i\zeta_p$ is a primitive $(4p)$th root of unity, so we have a field of degree $\phi(4p)=2(p-1)$ over $\mathbb Q$ contained in a field of degree $\phi(p)=p-1$ over $\mathbb Q$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hi Greg .Here Im not getting why  is $i\zeta_p$  a primitive $(4p)$th root of unity ?  why not $i\zeta_p$  is a primitive $(2p)$th root of unity ?

Comment: Since $p$ is odd, $2p\equiv2\pmod 4$ and thus $(i\zeta_p)^{2p} = i^{2p}(\zeta_p^p)^2 = -1\cdot1\ne1$.

Comment: okay @Greg Martin Thanks You Sir.